# How to unlock NVME disk locked with ATA security

Tags: hard-drive, security, nvme

I've locked my NVME drive in the BIOS with a USER and MASTER password.
I'm looking to unlock this drive on another machine.

How can I do this?

I've tried working with nvme-cli. This should be able to send security commands but I can't find any concrete information.

There is a tool which could help: https://github.com/jethrogb/nvme-ata-security
However that tool has it's own way to generating a password so it's incompatible.

Any hints?

Comment: the unlock keys are stored on the other PC, not on the disk itself, so I don't think you can.

Comment: In the end it wasn't possible to unlock the disk via another machine.

Comment: There are services out there that can unlock certain drives....